# Evaluating inline code inside a source block in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Sometimes in combinatoric programming it is helpful to explain the 
meaning of certain threshold values in code blocks. Example:

```
if x > 20 # combi(20,4) == 4845 is too large
then
    value_too_large()
else
    continue the computation
```

Is there a way to compute and expand this `4845` part in org-mode's code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about doing it directly in the `org` file.

What can be done is using `C-c '` which is `M-x org-edit-special`

from the doc:

```
(org-edit-special &optional ARG)

Call a special editor for the element at point.
When at a table, call the formula editor with ‘org-table-edit- 
formulas’.
When in a source code block, call ‘org-edit-src-code’.
When in a fixed-width region, call ‘org-edit-fixed-width-region’.
When in an export block, call ‘org-edit-export-block’.
When in a LaTeX environment, call ‘org-edit-latex-environment’.
When at an #+INCLUDE keyword, visit the included file.
When at a footnote reference, call ‘org-edit-footnote-reference’
On a link, call ‘ffap’ to visit the link at point.
Otherwise, return a user error.
```

in Clojure for example using `cider` you can evaluate any line or part or region into a comment using 'eval-last-sexp-and-insert' as well as other functions.

In `elisp` `lisp-interaction-mode` you can `evaluate-and-print`.

there's something similar in `lpy` for `Python`.
So it basically depends on the editing-mode which can also be configured in `.emacs`, for example `cider` for `Clojure` will be:

```
(setq org-babel-clojure-backend 'cider)
```

Comment: I see. So the steps are:1. C-c ' and enter into the narrowed buffer with the major mode, 2. do mode-specific expansion in the buffer.

Comment: and finish with `C-c '` to go back to org mode  and save there (.. or also `C-c C-s` in that editing buffer for save)